# audio record package for Flutter

Tags: audio-recording, audio-player

I am writing an App for children to learn to speak/listen Chinese. What is the best Flutter package for recording audio and playing audio? Specifically, I am considering either flutter_sound or the combination of record and just_audio. Can you give me some advices? Thanks.

I looked at their webpages. flutter_sound seems to meet my needs, but its last update was 19 months ago. I am concerned of its support. The combination of record and just_audio seems to be a good choice, but I don't need a lot of features.